# Implement a group of Java generics functions named `toJson()`

Tags: java, generics

I want to implement a group of generic functions named `toJson()` to convert objects to JSON strings.  Very similar to this post, [How to symmetrically implement serialize and deserialize template functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684670/how-to-symmetrically-implement-serialize-and-deserialize-template-functions-in-c)

For now I only need to support the following types `boolean`, `double`, `int` ,`long`,  `String` , array and `ArrayList`, and allow arbitrary combinations such as `int[][][][][]`, `ArrayList<ArrayList<int[]>>`, etc.

Serializer.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface Serializer {
    static String toJson(boolean value) {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
    static String toJson(double value) {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
    static String toJson(int value) {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
    static String toJson(long value) {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
    static String toJson(final String value) {
        return "\"" + value + "\"";
    }

    static <T> String toJson(final T value) {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    static <T>  String toJson(final T[] value) {
        final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("[");

        for (final T i : value) {
            result.append(toJson(i));
            result.append(',');
        }

        if (value.length > 0) result.delete(result.length() - 1, result.length());

        result.append(']');

        return result.toString();
    }

    static <T>  String toJson(final ArrayList<T> value) {
        final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("[");

        for (final T i : value) {
            result.append(toJson(i));
            result.append(',');
        }

        if (value.size() > 0) result.delete(result.length() - 1, result.length());

        result.append(']');

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Unit tests:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.Arrays;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;


public class SerializerTest {

    @Test public void primitiveToJsonTest() {
        assertEquals("true", Serializer.toJson(true));
        assertEquals("123.0", Serializer.toJson(123.000));
        assertEquals("123", Serializer.toJson(123));
        assertEquals("123", Serializer.toJson(123L));
        assertEquals("\"123\"", Serializer.toJson("123"));
    }

    @Test public void containerToJsonTest() {
        System.out.println(Serializer.toJson(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5})); // not correct !
        assertEquals("[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]", Serializer.toJson(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5)));
        assertEquals("[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]", 
            Serializer.toJson(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5), Arrays.asList(6,7,8,9, 10))));
    }
}
```

The only problem is about arrays, it seems Java will treat `T[]` as `T`.

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, generic arrays in Java are weird. Secondly, method dispatch in Java isn't dependent on the actual type of the method parameter, only the formal type. So all your array elements will be serialized with `static <T> String toJson(final T value)`, except strings, which will probably cause a compile error due to ambiguous signatures.

Comment: this code compiles, actually `toJson(final String value)` will never get called by ` toJson(final T[] value)` or `toJson(final ArrayList<T> value)`, both of them will always call `toJson(final T value)`

Comment: Okay, I finally get what your intention was, I completely misunderstood it at first. Sorry. :)

Answer (score 1):

The array case you have implemented only covers object arrays (e.g. `Integer[]`), you'll need to handle `int[]` and other primitive array types separately -- just like you handle `int` etc.

This is a problem only for the first level. In the case of `int[][]` etc., the "outer" array is an object array, as `int[]` is an `Object` so it's sufficient to cover one level.

Comment: How to support multiple dimensional arrays? For example, `int[][][][][][]`, the  C++ code can supports this, how does Java achieve this?

Comment: int[] is an Object, so it's fine, you only need to cover one level. Have edited the answer to better clarify this

Comment: But the `ArrayList<T>` works fine , the code above supports any level of `ArrayList<T>`, it seems the Java compiler will treat `T[]` as `Object[]` so it will not infer the right type for elements in an array, but it will infer the element type for `ArrayList`, weird...

Comment: Well you can't have ArrayList<int>, only ArrayList<Integer> or ArrayList<int[]>, and Integer[] works, but you want to get int[] working. Arrays of primitive type are objects, but not object arrays, that's the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Only reference types can be generic, for example, `C<T>`,  both `C` and `T` should be reference types.

if `T[]` matches to `int[]`, then `T` will be `int` which is a primitive type, so `T[]` won't match `int[]`, instead it will match `T`. This is the reason

```
Serializer.toJson(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5})
```

will call `static <T> String toJson(final T value)`

So the right way is to change  `new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}` to `new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5})`, since `Integer` is a reference type, `Integer[]` can match to `T[]`.

By only using templates, you're not able to write `toJson()` like in C++, because C++'s template is more powerful at compile time. You have to use both templates and reflection to achieve the same goal.